# Why eclipse does't autocomplete h: and f: tags?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, autocomplete

Why eclipse does't autocomplete h: and f: tags? But it autocompletes p: ui: and c: tags. How to enable autocomplete support for those?

Comment: Why should it autocomplete those in the file you're editing? Would they be known at runtime?

Comment: Surelly, those are present in server libraries.

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Which JSF impl/version? Do you have duplicate JSF libraries anywhere in the build path?

Comment: @BalusC Eclipse Kepler, jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec_2.0.1.Final.jar
Maybe it's because p: managed by maven but  jboss-jsf is used as server runtime libraries? There are no duplikates - only server runtime libraries and primefaces by maven.

Comment: Ah, Maven. I remember something with explicitly setting a provided-scoped JSF API+impl of the target version in pom. Give it a try.